# Images loading from akamai not caching in the browser

Tags: image, caching, header, preload, akamai

Images loading from akamai not caching in the browser.

when looking through developer window i see this in the header:

**Accept-Ranges**   bytes

**Access-Control-Allow-Cred...**    true

**Access-Control-Allow-Orig...**    *

**Access-Control-Request-He...**    X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin

*

> **Cache-Control** max-age=0, no-cache, no-store

*

**Connection**  Keep-Alive

**Content-Length**  114069

**Content-Type**    image/jpeg

**Date**    Tue, 02 Jul 2013 14:20:52 GMT

> **Etag**  "01bd6c5172ce1:0"
>
> **Expires**   Tue, 02 Jul 2013 14:20:52 GMT

**Last-Modified**   Wed, 26 Jun 2013 00:11:58 GMT

**Pragma**  no-cache

**Server**  Microsoft-IIS/7.5

**Set-Cookie**  BNI__BARRACUDA_LB_COOKIE=00000000000000000000000097f7ab4200005000; Path=/; 
**HttpOnly**
**X-CFLO-Cache-Result** TCP_NC_MISS

**X-Powered-By**    ASP.NET

What can i do to forces Akamai Servers to change the images header so it can be cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Akamai preserve Cache-Control header. If you don't setup Cache-Control your application/web server, is very recommendation that you do. But, if you want create specific policies using Akamai, you will need to enable the "Set Browser Cache Control Headers".